# Decompile own class from dll and pdb files Visual Studio

Tags: c#, onedrive, decompiling

I have this Visual Studio project that I'm working on, and I'm having it on OneDrive.

OneDrive messed up, and didn't sync the folder recently while I made changes, and now it did, and it brought back all the old class files.

I have compiled dll, pdb and manifests and all kinds of files but the sourcecode version is 10 versions older than the currently published prototype.

Is there any way, that I can bring back the class files from these dll, pdb and manifest files?

Comment: " I'm having it on OneDrive" That's the problem. Use source control systems like git, tfs. [Here we go](https://github.com/)

Comment: No.  If you don't have access to the latest .exe, no amount of chicken sacrificing will resurrect your source code.  As Sriram said, use source control

Comment: It's not an executable. It's a plugin (addin) so there's no need for an .exe.
Any chance that would help?

Comment: .dll?  .exe? It does not matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)? It allows you decompile .NET assemblies.

Comment: Thanks! This helped. I never mentioned an executable, so the dll is more than enough for this. It kinda did the job!